# M_construct error when reading file contents

Tags: c++, ifstream, stdstring

I'm creating a game that requires a lot of setup. I decided to add a configuration file (.ini) and a reader to get the information. My ini file is setup as follows:

```
-cmd arg0 arg1
```

I initially only had one command which worked fine until I added a second. For whatever reason, I receive an std::logic_error when my command is not the first one.

```
// this works
-load w "someName"

// this doesn't
-delete "someName"
```

Here is the code used to read the file:

```
InitFileReader::InitFileReader()
{
    std::string ini_file_path = "";
    ini_file_path += PROGRAM_FOLDER;
    ini_file_path += "\\blockgame.ini";
    std::ifstream ini_file(ini_file_path);

    if (!ini_file.is_open()) std::cout << "Couldn't find configuration file at " << ini_file_path << std::endl;

    std::string line;

    while(std::getline(ini_file, line))
    {
        if (starts_with(line, "-load "))
        {
            std::string arg0 = "";

            unsigned int index = 6;
            for (; index < line.size(); index++)
            {
                char c = line[index];
                if (c == ' ') break;

                arg0 += c;
            }

            std::string arg1 = "";
            bool reached_quote = false;

            for (; index < line.size(); index++)
            {
                char c = line[index];
                if (c == ' ' && !reached_quote) continue;

                if (c == '\"' && !reached_quote)
                {
                    reached_quote = true;
                    continue;
                }
                else if (c == '\"') break;

                arg1 += c;
            }

            sfr = new SaveFolderReader(arg1);

            if (arg0 == "new")
            {
                sfr->new_header(DEFAULT_HEADER);
            }
            else if (arg0 == "def")
            {
                sfr->restore_header(DEFAULT_HEADER);
            }
        }
        else if (starts_with(line, "-delete "))
        {
            std::string arg0 = "";

            unsigned int index = 8;
            for (; index < line.size(); index++)
            {
                char c = line[index];
                if (c == ' ') break;

                arg0 += c;
            }

            std::string world_path = "";
            world_path += PROGRAM_FOLDER;
            world_path += "\\save\\";
            world_path += arg0;

            if (rmdir(world_path.c_str()) != 0)
            {
                std::cout << "Error deleting world \"" << arg0 << "\"" << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }
}

inline bool starts_with(const std::string& target, const std::string& prefix)
{
    if (target.size() < prefix.size())
        return false;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < prefix.size(); i++)
    {
        if (target[i] != prefix[i])
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

The `PROGRAM_FOLDER` constant is just the parent folder of the path returned by `argv[0]` in main. I can't run the debugger on this code because the path changes to something strange when I do that.

I know that this error shows up because of a nullptr initialization of std::string but I still have no idea why this is happening.

I've tried typing in random characters into the config file and get the same result. It baffles me that the first if-statement works fine but the second one doesn't (when I use the -delete command).

Any suggestions would be of great use, thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried to step through your code line by line in a debugger to see what happens?

Comment: I stated in my question that that is not possible

Comment: When behavior changes between release and debug builds, or between running outside or inside a debugger, that's usually a sign of some *undefined behavior* in your code.

Comment: Yes but the path variable that I get from the main function looks like this when I run the debugger: C:/path_to_folder/bin/Debug[unknown character x6]/program.exe. Besides, my program has always worked before but I was never able to run the debugger.

Comment: You should probably ask a separate question about that issue, providing a proper [mcve] of course.

Comment: It is not my issue right now though. My issue is the std::string error that I'm trying to resolve

Comment: But if it prevents you from properly debugging your application, then it's an issue that should be taken seriously, as using a debugger is the best way to solve the problem you ask about in this question. It could also be a sign of some other and bigger problem. And if it's because of UB, then all bets are off since who knows what other problem might crop up because of that.

Comment: Anyway, there are other ways to debug, like "printf" debugging where you add a lot of `std::cout` output to show steps being done and the values of variables. Don't forget to flush the buffers all the time though. It's not as effective as using a debugger, but could help narrow down a problem.

Comment: That's my issue. All of the std::cout << std::endl statements yield good results. All of the strings seem to be initialized properly

Comment: Could it be missing double-quote handling in the `-delete` case that causes problem? I copied your code with some slight modifications and [tried it here](https://ideone.com/knbsea). It shows that you keep the double-quotes in `arg0` for the `-delete` case.

Comment: It's interesting that you mention that because it is a flaw in my code but in this case it doesn't actually make a difference. I also checked the world_header_path and it was right so the problem lies elsewhere. But thanks for the code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the error wasn't coming from that block of code at all. What was happening was that my game tried to load data in afterwards but because I didn't write the load command there was nothing to read from. I fixed my Debugger issue (For whatever reason the char[] I allocated stored different data when the debugger ran) and just reverted to std::strings.